# Integer Conversion into Time(6) in Teradata

Tags: timestamp, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have 2 fields SLA_HR and  SLA_MIN in integer ans want to convert into time(6) by concatenating 2 fields SLA_HR and SLA_MIN

Examp
Table xyz

```
SLA_HR SLA_MIN
4        6
12       30
```

Result :-
04:06:00
12:30:00

It would be great if anyone can help on this.

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest was is to cast the hours/minutes to intervals:

```
TIME '00:00:00' + Cast(SLA_HR AS INTERVAL HOUR) + Cast(SLA_MIN AS INTERVAL MINUTE)
```

To simplify reusing this calculation you should store it as a SQL UDF.