# Teradata Error 5407 when casting INTEGER to TIME

Tags: sql, teradata

This seems like it should be simple, I have two fields in a table. One is a DATE field and the other is an INTEGER. I am trying to combine these into a single DATETIME.

```
SELECT datefield,
       timefield,
       CAST(datefield AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + CAST(timefield as TIME(0)) AS datetimefield
FROM table;
```

The INTEGER field is storing the time where 0 should be 00:00:00 and 235959 is 23:59:59. Because the datefield is a DATE type already, casting it to TIMESTAMP(0) works. The issue is when I try to cast the INTEGER field to TIME(0). I get an error 5407 'Invalid operation for DateTime'.

So I tried to cast to character then to time. Same error. I tried to cast to time with a format of 'hh:mi:ss'. Same error.

As a last attempt I tried:

```
SELECT CAST(235959 AS TIME(0));
```

Same error. So I am stumped and searches only point to things I have already tried. What am I missing?

Comment: You just stumped the system.  How could the system possibly know that an integer 235959 be translated to time "23:59:59"???  You would probably have more luck if the type is a string.  Even a string, I don't think it will work.  Try string "23:59:59".  It may work.

Comment: [Convert Integer to Timestamp in Teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453588/convert-integer-to-timestamp-in-teradata) has an unaccepted answer, but does it help?

Comment: To format it as time, just use `SELECT 235959  (FORMAT '99:99:99')`.  To actually convert it, you should be able to work it out from the answer linked above, I think, or from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49315021/2751573)

Comment: @Andrew - This just returns the same 235959, I already tried this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you don't really want to convert to `TIME`. In order to add an offset to `TIMESTAMP` your 235959 needs to be converted to `INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND`.  The second problem is that there is no built-in conversion for an "encoded integer value" with different units. But there are multiple indirect ways to convert the INTEGER to the desired INTERVAL:

```
/* Extract each unit and use as a multiplier */
((timefield/10000)*INTERVAL '1' HOUR)+(((timefield/100) MOD 100)*INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)+((timefield MOD 100)*INTERVAL '1' SECOND)

/* Essentially the same but use unit conversion function */
NumToDSInterval(timefield/10000,'HOUR')+NumToDSInterval((timefield/100) MOD 100,'MINUTE')+NumToDSInterval((timefield MOD 100),'SECOND')

/* Calculate an equivalent integer in the most granular unit, then convert */
NumToDSInterval((timefield/10000)*3600+((timefield/100) MOD 100)*60+(timefield MOD 100),'SECOND')

/* Cast to a character string and back */
CAST(CAST(CAST(timefield AS FORMAT '99:99:99') AS CHAR(8)) AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND)
```

Or forget about the INTERVAL type and just build a string you can CAST to TIMESTAMP, such as

```
CAST(TO_CHAR(datefield)||CAST(CAST(timefield AS FORMAT '999999') AS CHAR(6)) AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT'yyyy/mm/ddhhmiss')
```

Comment: Painful, but this does work - thanks!